# Crystal Report filtering data with a function

Tags: filter, crystal-reports, report

We are using CR v14 to build reports from CSV.
We have a report that shows a list of disks with details like `Size`, `Used` and `Freespace`. Example:

```
Size    Used    FreeSpace
299,87  113,69  186,18
79,87   10,82   69,05
```

The data source of this report is a CSV file with more than 1000 entries.
The goal is to generate this report and list only disks with total used size equal or greater than 95%.
If I'm not wrong here is how to calculate it:

```
Freespace/Size * 100
```

But I have no idea how can I setup/insert it in the report.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in 2 ways, One from database side and other in crystal reports:

1. Calculation in Crystal Reports:

Place `Size Used Freespace` on to design in detail section and create a formula `@Calculate` and write below code:

```
Freespace/Size * 100
```

Place the formula after freespace in detail section.

Now go to the `supress` of the detail section and write below code:

```
EvaluateAfter({@Calculate});
if @Calculate<95
then true
else false
```

2 Database side implementation

Write a query and calculate in that query the calculation:

```
select Size, Used, Freespace, ((Freespace/Size) * 100) as cal from table
```

Now take this query in crystal reports and write the record selection formula as:

```
cal>95
```

Now place all fields in design part of crystal reports.

Edit...............................

`(ToNumber(Freespace)/ToNumber(Size)) * 100`

Comment: Thank you for your quick replay. When I writhe the code "Freespace/Size * 100" in function I get this error "the remaining text does not appear to be part of the formula crystal reports"

Comment: Try like this (Freespace/Size )* 100 else can you post your formula let me have a look once

Comment: Here is my formula (disks_csv.FreespaceGB/disks_csv.SizeGB)*100

Comment: This shouldnt produce any errors...what is the data type

Comment: Now it say "The(is missing". Where I can check the data type please?

Comment: Either your opening or closing braces are missing there should be an closing to opening brace and similar way an opening to closing brace...

Comment: You are some where missing the braces...post screenshot of crystal reports formula editor

Comment: Post crystal report screenshot

Comment: check your formula you wrote it wrong hence error..you wrote `(disk_csv.FreespaceGB/disks_csv.SizeGB)*100 ` but it should be `(disks_csv.FreespaceGB/disks_csv.SizeGB)*100 ` change it you will get result

Comment: Show your tables and structure

Comment: Can you guide me please? I down know in which section is it

Comment: When you open crystal to the right side there is field explorer there you can find tables

Comment: Here is the whole issue.....you are trying to manipulate the varchar fields as numbers...hence throwing error...now can you post some sample data of the fields you want to manipulate....I will try to provide solution